# How to Install latest Ubuntu LTS and keep existing Windows 10 Boot GUI on startup (No GRUB) - Legacy BIOS x64?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, installation

[Disk Management Setup - (Legacy BIOS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eH4o.jpg)

Hi, I have Legacy BIOS, and I want to Install the latest Ubuntu LTS (20.04.3 LTS) x64 on existing Multiple Windows OS System (Windows 10, XP, 2012 Server) Please See Disk Configuration image.  MBR on all 3 physical disks.
Windows Boot Manager is installed on on Disk0 (D:), and bootloaders are all 3 disks, with Windows 10 on Disk2 (C:) ordered first.

Ideally I want to install Ubuntu on physical Disk1 in the unformatted 216GB partition. Plan to set root to be about 50 GB, swap to be 6GB (=to physical RAM), and the rest ~160GB for /home.

/*I have USB sticks to use for x64 Ubuntu install (please suggest best tool to make bootable install for USB - I have Rufus, is it ok?)*/
**EDIT:
I downloaded and used [Rufus 3.17](https://rufus.ie/en/) to create bootable USB of [Unbuntu LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and followed [instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#2-requirements). It worked perfectly.**

I'm familiar with earlier Ubuntu versions and they always overwrote or replaced Windows boot manager loader with text OS Grub.  Ideally, I would like to keep using the existing Windows 10 Graphical multi-OS bootloader (with added Ubuntu line) after Ubuntu install. It would be ok if on selecting Ubuntu from WIndows 10 bootmenu it would bring me into Grub, but directly into Ubuntu would be ideal.

So, how to do this with least trouble? Is latest Ubuntu install smart enough to preserve the Windows 10 graphical boot, or must I take steps to avoid that manually, or post install repair? I would like to avoid the latter, of course. :).

Please let me know if I need to provide more info.
**I have researched this, but found comments unclear or not satisfactory to my situation.**

Thanks, John

P.S. I will back up existing Windows before installing Ubuntu... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I bit the bullet, and installed focal 20.04.3 LTS on my unformatted partition on my second hard drive as planned, using other installation option, making sure to install the Grub2 bootmenu/loader on that same drive (/boot).  Everything worked well during installation. When I restarted the pc, it went into the windows10  gui (Metro) boot  menu, and of course no  Ubuntu. since I left my 1st hard drive (0) as top boot priority in my Legacy BIOS.  However, once booted into Windows 10  **I used EasyBCD 2.4 and used Add New Entry option-Linux/BCD tab to add a Linux boot entry (Type: Grub2 , Name: Ubuntu, Drive:  1 Partition /boot  (1GB) ).** [Image of EasyBCD AddNewEntry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsp8Z.png) That's it.  I exited EasyBCD and restarted the machine and Ubuntu was added to the WINDOWS Gui Metro boot menu!!!

[Updated Windows Boot Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whuHm.jpg)

Note that when starting Ubuntu, the BIOS screen flashes again, then Grub2 boot menu appears, with choices for Ubuntu and Windows 2012 Server (since it is also installed on drive 1). When I choose Ubuntu, it loads right into Ubuntu.